# upload_files cap to not loggen in users - add_cap to not logged in users

Tags: filters, uploads, user-roles, rest-api, capabilities

When not logged in users upload files to the media endpoint, the return message is:

```
"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user."
```

I would like to allow not logged in users to be able to upload files.

I was looking for of the 3 solutions, but did not found any direction how to do one of these 3 options:

1. add_cap 'upload_files' to not logged in users
2. a way to prevent that cap check when files upload
3. a filter to set the a cap check to always true

This is for a local environment so security is not an issue here. May be they no option to to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: You can't add capabilities to logged out users. Even if you could, this is really reckless. Look into proper [authentication methods](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).

Comment: I second the comment by Jacob. If for any reason, security is not an issue (e.g. Intranet with trusted users) a 4th solution could be to have a dummy user, which has the right and is signed in, when doing the rest request.

Comment: instead of searching workaround, another idea is to create a new endpoint wich allow upload without authentication : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: @JacobPeattie its a local environment, I should have mentioned it in my question

Comment: @websupporter you mean every not logged in user would be a user, or somehow the endpoint will log in the users to the dummy users?

Comment: @mmm I'm aware of that option, but I wonder if they a way to achieve this on the the default media endpoint